# ms access mysql connection through php

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

i'm writing a program in which if I insert a row in any one of the table(of ms access or mysql) then same data should copied in other table.i'm able connect both databases but only mysql is responding correctly ms access not responding.writing code in php.

Comment: Yes you can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19808531/4584335

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect PHP with Microsoft Access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807081/how-to-connect-php-with-microsoft-access-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the ODBC Connector for this:
[MySQL ODBC Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

Comment: by that can access but values inserted through php are not available in ms access

Comment: It makes no difference from "where" records are inserted or updated. When saved, data will look the same from any client.